# Dimension of submanifold is lees or equal to the dimension of the manifold.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M \subset R^n$ be a $k$-dimensional smooth manifold.
I want to show that if $N \subset M$ is a smooth submanifold of $M$, then $dim(N) \le k$.

I am not really sure how to start solving this question. So I'll appreciate some clues on how to start.

Comment: What would it mean for a subset of a manifold to have dimension **greater** than the manifold?

Comment: What is your definition of a submanifold?

Comment: The definition of submanifold is the same as a manifold.

Comment: The only thing that I have here is that for every $x \in N$ there is an open neighborhood $U \subset R^n$ such that $N \bigcap U$ is a graph of a smooth function from $R^m$. I don't really see how it helps here.

Comment: Maybe the second definition can help more. That for every $x \in N$ there is a open neighborhood $U \subset R^n$ and a diffeomorphism $f: U \to f(U)$ such that $f(N \bigcap U) = R^m$x$\{0\}_{n-m}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A nonempty subset $M\subseteq \mathbb R^k$ is called a $m$-dimensional manifold if for every $x\in M$ there is an open neighbourhood $U\subseteq\mathbb R^k$ of $x$ and a diffeomorphims $\phi:U\to\phi(U)\subseteq\mathbb R^k$ such that $\phi(M\cap U)=\mathbb R^m\times\{0\}_{k-m}$.* We will show:

> If $ M\subseteq N\subseteq\mathbb R^k$ where $M$ is a $m$-dimensional  and $N$  a $n$-dimensional manifold then $m\leq n$.

Note  that this also implies that the rank of a manifold is well defined as you have asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157540/uniqueness-of-the-dimension-of-a-manifold).

$\textbf{proof}:$
Let $x\in M$ and choose diffeomorphims $\phi:U\to\phi(U)$, $\psi:V\to\psi(V)$ with $x\in U\cap V$ such that $\phi(M\cap U)=\mathbb R^m\times\{0\}_{k-m}$ and $\psi(N\cap V)=\mathbb R^n\times\{0\}_{k-n}$. 
For $q\leq k$ let $\text{inc}_q: \mathbb  R^q\to\mathbb R^k$ and $\text{pr}_q: \mathbb  R^k\to\mathbb R^q$ be the canonical inclusion and  projection and set $\tilde U=\text{pr}_m(\phi(U\cap V\cap M))\subseteq\mathbb R^m
$.

Then we have a smooth map

$$J:\tilde U\xrightarrow{\text{inc}_m}\phi(U\cap V)\xrightarrow{\psi\circ\phi^{-1}}\psi(U\cap V)\subseteq\mathbb R^k$$

By construction $J(\tilde U)\subseteq \mathbb R^n\times\{0\}_{k-n}$ so $\text{inc}_n\circ\text{pr}_n\circ J=J$. The Jacobian $D(J)=D(\text{inc}_n)\cdot D(\text{pr}_n\circ J)$ has rank $m$ everywhere and so $D(\text{pr}_n\circ J)\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ has at least rank $m$ which implies $m\leq n$. $\square$

$\textbf{Edit:}$
$\phi(U\cap V\cap  M)\subseteq \mathbb R^m\times\{0\}_{k-m}$, so
$\text{inc}_m\,(\tilde U)=\text{inc}_m\circ\text{pr}_m\circ\phi\,(U\cap V\cap  M)=\phi(U\cap V\cap  M)$,
$J(\tilde U)
=\psi\circ\phi^{-1}\circ\text{inc}_m\,(\tilde U)
=\psi\,(U\cap V\cap M)
\subseteq \psi\,( V\cap N)= \mathbb R^n\times\{0\}_{k-n}$

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you just explain what is "the canonical inclusion and projection"?

Comment: Yes maybe its not so canonical $inc_q(x_1,\dots,x_q)=(x_1,\dots,x_q,0,\dots,0)$  and  $pr_q(x_1,\dots,x_k)=(x_1,\dots,x_q)$ also i have to admit that $J(\tilde U)\subseteq \mathbb R^n\times\{0\}_{k-n}$ is not fully obious so if you want i can add the computation.

Comment: Yes, if you can add the computation it will help

Comment: could you maybe clarify about the last sentence, why $D(pr_n \circ J)$ has at least rank $m$, and why does this imply $m \le n$?

Comment: By the chain rule $D(J)=D(\text{inc}_n)\cdot D(\text{pr}_n\circ J)$. Since $D(J)$ has rank $m$ and [$rank(AB)\leq min\{rank A, rank B\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope) $rank(D(\text{pr}_n\circ J))\geq m$. But as $D(\text{pr}_n\circ J)$ is a $n\times m$ matrix $rank(D(\text{pr}_n\circ J))\leq n$ see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/is-the-rank-of-a-matrix-the-same-of-its-transpose-if-yes-how-can-i-prove-it).

Comment: Thanks again, now I fully understand